# Capturing only the closest match before a look ahead

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a bunch of playlist data in JSON format in a string. It's very large and I'm doing a lot of processing with it, so I'm attempting to extract information from it as a string instead of turning it into a JavaScript object.

I'm trying to obtain the playlist name of every playlist that contains some song name. For example, I'm attempting to get `playlist 1` and `playlist 3` of the following string if I'm looking for `song 1`:

```
{"playlist 1":["song 3","song 1"],"playlist 2":["song 2"],"playlist 3":["song 1"]}
```

To do so, I'm using the following regex:

```
"([^"]*?)":(?=.*song 1)
```

but this is capturing *all* playlist names before `song 1`, not just the most immediate playlist name before `song 1`.

How can I only capture the closest one to the forward look ahead? I tried using a negative look ahead for this but couldn't get one working.

https://regex101.com/r/gW2cL1/15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace this `(?=.*song 1)` at your regex  by this `(?=[^\]]+song 1)` and that said.

```
"([^"]*?)":(?=[^\]]+song 1)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gW2cL1/18)

Comment: That works. I was overthinking the situation, as is usually true when I run into errors XD